# HTML showing every capital A letter as image of head

Tags: html, css

Suddenly in HTML all capital "A" are shown as head icon of a man. Image attached. I don't know what happened. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Corrupted font file I'd suggest. What happens when you change the font?

Comment: Thanks. Its working now after changing the font type. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```